# Generic methods in C# not calling most restrictive overload

Tags: c#, linq, generics, overloading, ienumerable

I have overloaded generic methods that look like this:

```
public static T DoSomething<T>(T val) 
{
    return val;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> vals) 
{
    return vals.Select(x => DoSomething(x));
}
```

The problem I am running into is that the following code won't compile:

```
var myList = new List<SomeObject>();

// This will not compile
PropertyOfTypeIEnumerable_SomeObject = MyStaticClass.DoSomething(myList);
```

The compiler is complaining that it can't convert `SomeObject` into `IEnumerable<SomeObject>`. This indicates that the compiler is choosing the first version of DoSomething, which takes generic type T, as opposed to the second version, which takes the more restrictive generic type IEnumerable.

I can confirm this is the case by renaming the second overloaded method to DoSomethingList and calling that name explicitly:

```
public static T DoSomething<T>(T val) 
{
    return val;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> DoSomethingList<T>(IEnumerable<T> vals) 
{
    return vals.Select(x => DoSomething(x));
}

// ...

var myList = new List<SomeObject>();

// This compiles ok
PropertyOfTypeIEnumerable_SomeObject = MyStaticClass.DoSomethingList(myList);
```

My question is, why doesn't the compiler choose the most restrictive matching generic implementation to call, and is there any way I can get that behavior without having to name it uniquely and call it explicitly? If the example were calling overloads for different objects which inherited from one another, then it would choose the most restrictive overload based on the declared variable type. Why doesn't it do this for generics as well?

Another option would be to not overload the methods, but to check inside of the DoSomething method to see if T is assignable from IEnumerable<>, but then I don't know how to actually cast it to something I could call the Linq method on, and I don't know how to get the compiler to be ok with returning the result of that Linq method, since *I* will know that the return result needs to be IEnumerable, but the *compiler* will not.

Comment: Does it call the correct method if you cast you list to IEnumerable, eg var enumerableList = (IEnumerable<SomeObject>)myList.

Comment: Like @AnilGoel said. As a `List` it should be calling `T` method first as it always look for matching derivation before implementation. If the `IEnumerable<T>` method parameter was changed to `List<T>` then it should technically pick this one first.

Comment: Which method would you expect a `string` to call? It also implements `IEnumerable`

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [mcve] - this is *nearly* that, but not quite enough to be able to just reproduce it. I would personally suggest avoiding the overload here. Note that your idea of "most restrictive" basically doesn't match the specification - you need to understand that the inferred `T` is different between the different methods, so you're effectively calling `DoSomething<List<SomeObject>>` with an argument of type `List<SomeObject>`, which *exactly* matches the parameter type of the first method.

Comment: @SeanWorle If you look at [the signature for the `string` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8281103e6f23cb5c.html), it implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<char>`. Where do you see that *"it does NOT implement `IEnumerable<T>`"*? Also, the *"pretty obviously"* comment seems rude. Did I say something to offend you?

Comment: @RufusL You're right, that was pretty rude of me - i apologize for that.
You are also right that the implementation does implement IEnumerable<T> - I was going to say that the documentation didn't indicate that, but now I look again and see that it does. I'm not sure how what I was looking at. I probably simply wasn't looking closely enough. I'm going to delete my original comment, as it was in poor judgement. Thank you for your patience with me.

Answer (score 2):

Generics in C# differ in many ways from C++ templates [(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics). You'd be right that it would call the more restrictive `IEnumerable<T>` function if we were working in C++ meta-programming. However, in C# the `<T>` function matches `List<T>` better, because it is more exact.

I tested your code above and it compiles just fine for me on .NET v4.0.30319 but it returns a `List<T>` type instead of the expected reduced `IEnumerable<T>` type that a Select call returns. Indicating that the `<T>` function was called.

If you want to perform `DoSomething` on all objects in `IEnumerable` extended classes, then here is a way to do so:

```
public static T DoSomething<T>(T val)
{
    switch (val)
    {
        case IEnumerable vals:
            foreach (object x in vals)
                DoSomething(x);
            break;
    }

    return val;
}
```

I've set it up in a way that allows for matching other specific types, as I'd guess that each different type is going to do something different. If that is not intended you can always use just a simple `if...is` statement matching.

Comment: Not bad (in my opinion) but you lose strong typing on the object in the IEnumerable

Comment: For example, if object x is of type `string`, `DoSomething<object>` will be called instead of the preferred `DoSomething<string>`

Comment: Sorry yes, you're right, but there is hardly ever a case where that matters unless you are using default(T) or typeof(T). val.GetType() will still return the proper type.

Comment: Also using the pattern matching switch like I have above will work for any type or interface that the (object T) matches. So strong typing is not as big a worry as in c++.

Comment: Actually you don't even need a generic parameter here,  `public static object DoSomething(object val)` will work just as well, so you're just overcomplicating it by using a generic here.

Comment: Actually, by returning T type you get the strongly typed object back to reuse. You don't have to worry about type matching outside the function then. I.E. DoSomething(ReactiveClass).ReactiveMethod()
What you put in is what you get back.

Comment: Completely disagree but too big of a discussion for this forum.